# How to bundle AngularJS, WebAPI 2 web application as an Cordova package

Tags: angularjs, cordova, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-cordova

I have an VS.Net 2013, Asp.Net WebAPI-2, AngularJS 1.4 portal which I would like to convert it to an Cordova package to speed up the application start time. At this moment there is no real need to access any native features of on the Phone. Its a responsive web pages so it does fit well on the phone form factor, but on the slow network, it takes a while to open the page each time b'cos some of the images used.

I was wondering if someone can help me understand:

1. If there is any recommended approach to maintain a common code base for both the webpage and the Cordova App as it's already responsive.
2. My Angular services to access the WebAPI looks somewhat like is:-

   ```
   function checkUserAccess(fnSuccess, fnError) {
   return $resource( * * "/api/authorization/user/checkaccess" * * , {}, {
     "checkAccess": {
       method: "POST",
       isArray: false
     }
   })
   .checkAccess({}, {}, fnSuccess, fnError);
   ```

   }

but when it's converted to a Cordova application, I think we will have to give a full URI along with my domain name. So is there a simpler way to enable adding a domain name prefix only in the case of Cordova build without haveing to hardcode all the service calls?

Answer (score 0):

Sure I have several apps in the same tech stack you mentioned

Regarding a **single code base**: When writing Cordova everything you write is inside a www/ folder as js, html, and css. Cordova takes this and creates mobile app packages elsewhere. If your code is the same across both all you need to do is deploy this www/ package to a website and you're all set. No extra work to maintain a separate code base or anything.

The only issue I can think of is the import script for Cordova will fail. As long as your code doesn't make any Cordova calls you're fine, and you could always wrap those in an if(Cordova) to cover your bases.

Regarding **API URI**: You will need to provide some hard-coded endpoint somewhere or else your cordova app will have no clue where to go. You could

1) Just load up your serviceBase in a config.json or hard-coded in your app.run
  2) Create a single service for getEndpoints residing at a static address (referenced by #1 above), which returns the locations of all your other endpoints